# Limited HTTP traffic

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm experiencing a weird limited connectivity scenario with my Linux network stack.
The problem is that whenever I try to download something, I can only get the first 5.5KB of the requested resource, **both** with my ethernet card (Realtek 8139), and through my wireless card (IPW2200).
For example:

- wget google.it => I will get a full 'index.html' page (as it's 4.9KB)
- wget google.it/intl/it_it/images/logo.gif => I will get the first 5.5KB of the image and wget will hang, undefinitely waiting for the remaining part of the image
- [capture of HTTP conversation to www.polito.it](http://www.qitty.net/tmp/polito.pcap) (6) (as you can see in this capture, no further requests are going out, even if the page is missing some elements)

---

Environment&tools:

- I try seeing the pages through both Firefox and command-line Links, both from my local installation and from Live CDs
- **on Windows both network cards are working perfectly** without any issue (I'm writing from the dual-booted Windows right now)
- this problem is happening **on every Linux distro** I have tried (each with different kernels): ArchLinux, Live ArchLinux 2007.08, grml 2008, grml 2009.10

---

Here is my Linux configuration:

- the kernel is detecting the card (module 8139too or ipw2200) and assign to it a good IRQ
- the DHCP server (at 192.168.1.1) is correctly assigning the IP 192.168.1.2 to my network interface. Example of ethernet one:

  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:9f:be:77:da
        inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:9fff:febe:77da/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
        RX bytes:163064 (159.2 KiB)  TX bytes:40610 (39.6 KiB)
        Interrupt:16 Base address:0xc000
- the MTU is set to 1500, but even with smaller values the problem is still there (I tried values of 1492, 1454, 1000, 500)
- the DNS resolution is working good
- the pings to other hosts on the network/internet are ok:

  PING www.l.google.com (74.125.43.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from bw-in-f104.1e100.net (74.125.43.104): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=52.1 ms
  64 bytes from bw-in-f104.1e100.net (74.125.43.104): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=50.9 ms
- there is no timeout/full receive buffers/unhandled IRQs messages indicated by the kernel

I have no other ideas about why this is happening...
Apart fom this, this issue is reproducible and for any web-page, it stops loading after a give amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem: my gateway is not properly handling the TCP Window Scaling.
Therefore, I instructed my Linux kernel not to use this functionality and now the connection is working smoothly.

For your info, here is my patch into the network configuration.
In /etc/sysctl.conf I added the following lines:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0
```

And this was the identification of my router: "Alice Gate 2 Plus Wi-Fi" with firmware version "AGIA_1.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

If as you say it is working on Windows fine and you are having problems on various Linux distributions, it is possible that the Linux driver is simply bad.

I would personally file a bug report or see if you can find a different version of the driver.

Also, I am a little confused on one point -

> I try seeing the pages through both Firefox and command-line Links, both from my local installation and from Live CDs

Are you saying that you have tried and it works or fails?

If works, try ripping the driver from the live CD. If it fails, you may be out of luck.

At no point should you have to manually mess around with MTU or other technical items... I always say things like that are there so you can fine tune it once you know it is already working (so you know what to go back to if there is an error!), but if it doesn't work by default, it is some other sort of fault that you should look at first.

Comment: I tried with all the four combinations:
-local installation of firefox
-local installation of links
-firefox launche from Live CD
-links launched from Live CD
but none of them worked: they are all showing the same problem.

I am currently finding out whether the 8139too driver has not been modified throughout all the kernels I've been trying so far...and eventually I'll go look for an older/newer kernel&driver.