# WiFi suddenly becomes deadly slow on browsers on Ubuntu 22.03

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, browser

Today my WiFi connection got very slow apparently with no reason (at least, I can't find one).

When I’m only using browser (Firefox standard) stay very low, around 50KiB/s with a few short-raises.

When I open Transmission and a fully-legal movie download from TPB download rates reaches 5 MB/s.

Illustrating:

Network traffic with Tranmission running:
[image: Network traffic with Tranmission running]

Network traffic after Transmission being closed:
[image: Network traffic after Transmission being closed]

Network traffic with only youtube/firefox open:
[image: Network traffic with only youtube/firefox open]

What I’ve tried so far:

1. Change the MTU from wireless interface from 1500 to 1492;
2. Add to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` the following:

   ```
   options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
   ```
3. `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`
4. Set `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` variable `wifi.` from 3 to 2;
5. Upgrade Firefox version.

Does anyone have an idea?

---

**Edit**: Also tried this solution, but with no change:

- [Limited HTTP traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/88189/limited-http-traffic)

Comment: I'm not sure I see a problem here? Your graphs show network _traffic,_ not network speed – and websites do not continuously generate network traffic once they're loaded...

Comment: @John I use neighbor internet, so i do not have access to router. I'll try update wireless card

Comment: @u1686_grawity i see your point. The fact is that not even pseudo-videos on youtube are being playing fairly. A song or a 144p video get stucked dozens of time

Comment: Do videos on _other_ sites (e.g. Twitch) play better or is it the same for all of them?

Comment: @John my smartphone and another laptop are both connected on same router and working just fine. Other laptop also run an ubuntu

Comment: Use wavemon, https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon, to check the WiFi connection. The connection may be high-speed, but if the *website* or your neighbor's *router* throttle traffic, throughput would be slow.